# Expressing the act of drawing

Tags: kanji

Can the kanji for writing 「書き」be used to express that one is drawing something, like a picture「絵」. As in 絵は書きます read as えはかきます.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For drawing, we use 「描{か}く」 as in 「絵{え}を描く」.

「書{か}く」 is reserved for writing letters and characters. So, we say 「字{じ}を書く」, 「文章{ぶんしょう}を書く」, etc.

Note that the two are originally the same verb.  They are only written using different kanji for disambiguation.

Comment: What about 描く read as えがく?

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/egaku